# How to open a popup window dialog box when clicked on the context menu in crossridder ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-extension, crossrider

I have created an extension successfully and I am using an alert in extension.js to show the final message to the user when he clicks on the context menu but I want a customized popup window dialog box created using js and html instead of javascript alert.

Please help how can I do that. My extension works for the links on the webpages . when right button is clicked it shows the context menu and when clicked it throws the alert but I want to show a nice popup for the message.

Comment: can you please better explain what do you mean by "popup window" ? Is it an overlay on the page, or an actual new window instance ?

Comment: See the demo here:-http://techpython.com/demo.html

Comment: In the above demo, I need to click on the hyperlink then a popup or you can say a floater comes. I want to implement the same popup to open when a command in my contextMenu is clicked.

Comment: Ya ! It's an overlay on the page itself

Answer (score 2):

The key is understanding the [scopes](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/scopes) in which your code is running. The [context menu](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.contextMenu) runs in the background scope and does not have direct access to the DOM of the active page. Hence, to implement a solution you must [pass information](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message) from the background scope to the extension's page scope, and in that scope create the custom popup OR use [Crossrider's notification plugin](http://crossrider.com/developer/plugins).

The following example demonstrates the implementation using the *notification plugin*:

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  // Handler to receive messages
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'show-notification')
      showNotification(msg.notification);
  });

  function showNotification(data) {
    // You can replace the notifier with your own custom code
    appAPI.notifier.show({
      'name':'my-notification-name',
      'title':data.title,
      'body':data.body,
      'link':'http://example.com',
      'theme':'default',
      'position':'top-right',
      'close':true,
      'sticky':false,
      'width':'400px',
      'closeWhenClicked':true
    });
  }
});
```

**Important**: Do not forget to add the *notification plugin* to the extension.

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.contextMenu.add(
    "CustomMI",
    "Custom menu item",
    function (data) {
      // Send message to active tab when context menu item selected
      appAPI.message.toActiveTab({
        type: 'show-notification',
        notification: {
          title: 'Context Menu Item',
          body: '<b>Veiwing page</b>: '+data.pageUrl
        }
      });
    }, ["all"]
  );
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Hi shiomo,
how can I increase the height of the iframe ?

Comment: If you mean the height of the notification, the height auto adjusts to the body content height. However, if you require more granular control, you can inject styling CSS with the body HTML content to set the height (e.g. 600px), such that your body property passed to the notifier becomes: `'body':'<style>div[name="my-notification-name"] > div {height:600px;}</style>' + data.body`.